# how to select a checkbox in a table depending on the row value?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm working with to automate a GWT app.  There is a table with the following columns: checkbox, userID, Username, Fname, LName, Email.

Here's the code for a single row in the table:

```
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</td>
<td class="GB1F3LJFQ GB1F3LJKO" title="8902" align="right" style="height: 19px; width: 34px;">
<div style="height: 19px; width: 34px;">
<div class="gwt-HTML">8902</div>
</div>
</td>
<td class="GB1F3LJFQ GB1F3LJKO" title="Agency_Group_0_Agency_Group_Member_0_dan_all_features_6" align="left" style="height: 19px; width: 146px;">
<div style="height: 19px; width: 146px;">
<div class="gwt-HTML">Agency_Group_0_Agency_Group_Member_0_dan_all_features_6</div>
</div>
</td>
<td class="GB1F3LJFQ GB1F3LJKO" title="" align="left" style="height: 19px; width: 63px;">
<div style="height: 19px; width: 63px;">
<div class="gwt-HTML">

</div>
</div>
</td>
<td class="GB1F3LJFQ GB1F3LJKO" title="" align="left" style="height: 19px; width: 28px;">
<div style="height: 19px; width: 28px;">
<div class="gwt-HTML">

</div>
</div>
</td>
<td class="GB1F3LJFQ GB1F3LJKO" title="Agency_Group_0_Agency_Group_Member_0_dan_all_features_6@xxx.com" align="left" style="height: 19px; width: 146px;">
<div style="height: 19px; width: 146px;">
<div class="gwt-HTML">Agency_Group_0_Agency_Group_Member_0_dan_all_features_6@xxx.com</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The xpath to the checkbox is:
/html/body/div[6]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/div/div[1]/div/table[10]/tbody/tr/td[1]

The xpath to the username column is:
/html/body/div[6]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/div/div[1]/div/table[10]/tbody/tr/td[3]

My code loops through a list of names and it is supposed to click the checkbox associated with that name:
for name in memberlist:
        print 'clicking checkbox associated with %s' %name
        chrome.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[td[contains(text()='" + name + "')]]/td[1]").click()

The error I'm getting is:
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //tr[td[contains(text()='Agency_Group_0_Agency_Group_Member_0_dan_all_features_6')]]/td[1] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//tr[td[contains(text()='Agency_Group_0_Agency_Group_Member_0_dan_all_features_6')]]/td[1]' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=48.0.2564.116)

My question is:
How do I click the checkbox associated with the name?

Comment: Probably sometimes you need to mouse over it and then go ahead and click it. You know sometimes objects are not directly enabled, until mouse is hoovered on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You not using `contains()` correctly. Replace:

```
//tr[td[contains(text()='" + name + "')]]/td[1]
```

with:

```
//tr[td[contains(text(), '" + name + "')]]/td[1]
```

Comment: This helped a lot.  Thank you for the response.  This path got me to the point of realizing it won't work.  HOWEVER, the core ideas were very useful in actually solving the issue.  The code I ended up using was:

chrome.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[td[@title='" + name + "']]/td[1]/div").click()